# Bootstrap Example Not Rendering Gray Box. Everything Else Fine?

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I used 'view source page' and took all the html from the this example on the bootstrap website: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

It runs smoothly on my localhost using Django except for one small thing. That Gray Box within the sliding carousel doesn't appear? Oddly, if I put all the html into JSfiddle it's also missing.

I've included the CSS and works perfectly for everything else on the page:

```
<link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
<link href="carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

So my django page looks exactly like this: http://jsfiddle.net/yU9zE/1/

Funkylaundry has identified that some of the css isn't loading for some reason. He found this warnings/errors using a debugging tool called firebug:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)     http://fiddle.jshell.net/yU9zE/1/show/carousel.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://fiddle.jshell.net/yU9zE/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://fiddle.jshell.net/yU9zE/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://fiddle.jshell.net/yU9zE/assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://fiddle.jshell.net/yU9zE/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://fiddle.jshell.net/yU9zE/assets/js/docs.min.js
```

I'm not sure what to do because I'm new bootstrap and I usually just use a simple external css file. Should i be seeing new css files in my assets folder on django too? Becuase I don't. I'd love to get the gray box to appear, but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you did not hook your assets right (i.e. the carousel.css is never loaded). If you check your developer tools/firebug or whatever you're using you will see a bunch of 404s:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)     http://fiddle.jshell.net/yU9zE/1/show/carousel.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://fiddle.jshell.net/yU9zE/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://fiddle.jshell.net/yU9zE/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://fiddle.jshell.net/yU9zE/assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://fiddle.jshell.net/yU9zE/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://fiddle.jshell.net/yU9zE/assets/js/docs.min.js
```

Comment: Thanks for that. When you say 'assets' are you referring to my assets folder in Django? Because assets/css doesn't have any new css files in there after I perform a collectstatic. Should it?

Comment: By assets I mean your .css files and .js files. I don't know how Django organizes it's project, but your assets folder sound legit. Practice might be different, though, when you are importing a framwork like bootstrap. How did you make the jsfiddle in the first place? Copy the html rendered by Django? Because your file-paths won't be the same in jsfiddle and your local django environment.

Comment: For jsfiddle, and my django site, I simply copied the html from the bootstrap website (http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/) using view page source. I thought they provided all the css for you, but I'm not sure how this would get rendered: <link href="carousel.css" rel="stylesheet"> since I don't have it on my computer?

Comment: I figured out that I also had to copy over the css and js files to my assets folder. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I copied over all the js and css, but some of the files are very big: http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js Now my website is extremely slow. Is this normal? Should I have copied over the entire files?

Comment: There is always some overhead in terms of using frameworks like Bootstrap, but you are using the minified file which should be around 30k, so that's not really what I would consider big. Especially considering that you are probably developing on a local environment? If you ar eusing Chrome, you could open the dev tools and go to the tab "network" and then refresh the page to see what resources might be slowing down load times.